# hold longer will jump higher (C# winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, error-handling

I am trying to make a 2D game in winforms. i want my character to be able to double jump and if i hold the space key (jump) for a long time i will jump higher or if i hold the space key (jump) less i will jump lower (Note that although holding longer will jump higher, but only up to a fixed level, not to infinity). but I can only double jump and only jump 1 fixed distance, not hold the space longer to jump higher or hold it shorter to jump lower, someone help me, below is my code.

```
public partial class GamePlay_Page : Form
{
bool goRight, goLeft;
int gravity = 16;
int force;
bool jump;
int jumpTimes = 2;
public GamePlay_Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void GamePlay_Page_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
    {
        goRight = true;
        Trex.Image = Properties.Resources.running;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
    {
        goLeft = true;
        Trex.Image = Properties.Resources.running2;
    }
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && jumpTimes > 0)
    {
        jump = true;
        force = gravity;
        jumpTimes -= 1;

    }
    private void gameT(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (goRight == true && Trex.Right < 600)
        {
            Trex.Left += 5;
        }
        if (goLeft == true && Trex.Left > 10)
        {
            Trex.Left -= 5;
        }

        if (jump == true)
        {
            Trex.Top -= force;
            force -= 1;
        }
        if (Trex.Top + Trex.Height >= backgroundAbove.Height)
        {
            Trex.Top = backgroundAbove.Height - Trex.Height;
        }
        else
        {
            Trex.Top += 3;
        }
        if (Trex.Top + Trex.Height == backgroundAbove.Height)
        {
            jumpTimes = 2;
        }
        private void GamePlay_Page_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) { goRight = false; }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A) { goLeft = false; }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you mean, and change it according to your needs.

Please see my example:

Add a `stopwatch` to judge the length of the pressing time, in order to prevent the intensity from bursting.

What I set is to give a fixed force for pressing more than 3s, otherwise give an initial force for gravity.

Change it according to your needs.

You can completely change it to a force multiplied by time.

```
 Stopwatch watch =new Stopwatch();
 watch.Start();//start the timer
 watch.Stop(); //stop the timer
 watch.ElapsedMilliseconds// Show duration in milliseconds（Type is long）
 watch.Reset();//reset the timer
```

Put the timing start into the `KeyDown` event：

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && jumpTimes > 0)
    {
    //jump = true;
    //force = gravity;
    //jumpTimes -= 1;
    watch.Start();
    }
```

Put the timing end and trigger the jump into the `KeyUp` event：

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && jumpTimes > 0)
    {
    watch.Stop();
    jump = true;
    jumpTimes -= 1;
    if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 300)//>3s
        { 
        force = 30;        
        }
    else
        {
        force = gravity;
        }
    }
watch.Reset();
```

All the codes:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GamePlay_Page {
    public partial class GamePlay_Page : Form {
        public GamePlay_Page () {
            InitializeComponent();
            }
        bool goRight, goLeft;
        int gravity = 16;
        int force;
        bool jump;
        int jumpTimes = 2;
        Stopwatch watch =new Stopwatch();
        private void GamePlay_Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            }
        private void GamePlay_Page_KeyDown (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                {
                goRight = true;
                Trex.Image = Properties.Resources.ch;
                }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                {
                goLeft = true;
                Trex.Image = Properties.Resources.ca;
                }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && jumpTimes > 0)
                {
                //jump = true;
                //force = gravity;
                //jumpTimes -= 1;
                watch.Start();
                }
            }
        private void GamePlay_Page_KeyUp (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && jumpTimes > 0)
                {
                watch.Stop();
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W && jumpTimes > 0)
                    {
                    watch.Stop();
                    jump = true;
                    jumpTimes -= 1;
                    if (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 300)//>3s
                        {
                        force = 30;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        force = gravity;
                        }
                    }
                }
            watch.Reset();
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D)
                {
                goRight = false;
                }
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
                {
                goLeft = false;
                }
            
            }
        private void Timer1_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (goRight == true && Trex.Right < 600)
                {
                Trex.Left += 5;
                }
            if (goLeft == true && Trex.Left > 10)
                {
                Trex.Left -= 5;
                }

            if (jump == true)
                {
                Trex.Top -= force;
                force -= 1;
                }
            if (Trex.Top + Trex.Height >= backgroundAbove.Height)
                {
                Trex.Top = backgroundAbove.Height - Trex.Height;
                }
            else
                {
                Trex.Top += 3;
                }
            if (Trex.Top + Trex.Height == backgroundAbove.Height)
                {
                jumpTimes = 2;
                }
            G.Text = gravity.ToString();
            F.Text = force.ToString();
            T.Text = Trex.Top.ToString();
            L.Text = Trex.Left.ToString();
            J.Text = jumpTimes.ToString();
            W.Text = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

main page:

[image]

Output:

[image]

**If you have questions about my code, please comment below and I will follow up as soon as possible.**